# Alignment process in Nextflow not picking up the index files from the index process

Tags: nextflow

I'm using bowtie2 to build a small index. After building the index, I want to pass it to the bowtie2 alignment process. The issue is bowtie2-build outputs multiple index files with the .bt2 extension. When I try to provide these index files as an input to the Alignmnet process, it gives the following error:

> Error executing process > 'SAM_FOR_STRAND (1)'
>
> Caused by:   Process `SAM_FOR_STRAND (1)` terminated with an error
> exit status (255)
>
> Command executed:
>
> bowtie2 -t -x index.1.bt2 index.2.bt2 index.3.bt2 index.4.bt2
> index.rev.1.bt2 index.rev.2.bt2 -1 SRR5655560_1.atria.fastq -2
> SRR5655560_2.atria.fastq -S "SRR5655560.sam"
>
> Command exit status:   255
>
> Command output:   (empty)
>
> Command error:   (ERR): "index.1.bt2" does not exist or is not a
> Bowtie 2 index   Exiting now ...
>
> executor >  local (4) [71/c095e4] process > INDEX              [100%]
> 1 of 1 ✔ [1f/35a1e6] process > GTF2BED            [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
> [fa/b1e933] process > TRIM (SRR5655560)  [100%] 1 of 1 ✔ [d6/d47ead]
> process > SAM_FOR_STRAND (1) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘ Error
> executing process > 'SAM_FOR_STRAND (1)'
>
> Caused by:   Process `SAM_FOR_STRAND (1)` terminated with an error
> exit status (255)
>
> Command executed:
>
> bowtie2 -t -x index.1.bt2 index.2.bt2 index.3.bt2 index.4.bt2
> index.rev.1.bt2 index.rev.2.bt2 -1 SRR5655560_1.atria.fastq -2
> SRR5655560_2.atria.fastq -S "SRR5655560.sam"

The following is simplifies version of the pipeline:

```
// Declare syntax version
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

/* 
 * pipeline input parameters 
 */


params.reads = "$projectDir/data/*_{1,2}.fastq"
params.ref_genome = "$projectDir/data/Glycine_max.Glycine_max_v2.1.dna.toplevel.fa"
params.gtf_file = "$projectDir/data/Glycine_max.Glycine_max_v2.1.55.gtf"
params.outdir = "results"



log.info """\

        R N A S E Q - N F   P I P E L I N E    
        ===================================
        reads            : ${params.reads}
        reference genome : ${params.ref_genome}
        gtf              : ${params.gtf_file}
        outdir           : ${params.outdir}
        """
        .stripIndent()

/*
 * define the `index` process that creates a binary index
 * given the reference genome file
 */

process INDEX {

  input:
  path ref_genome

  output:
  path "index.*"

  script:
  """
  bowtie2-build $ref_genome index
  """
}

/*
 * define the `GTF2BED` process that creates a BED file
 * given the params.gtf_file as input. 
 */
 
process GTF2BED {

    input:
    path gtf

    output:
    path "${gtf.baseName}.bed"

    script:
    """
    gtf2bed --gtf "${gtf}" --bed "${gtf.baseName}.bed"
    """
}


/*
 * define the `TRIM` process that creates trimmed fastq files
 * given the reads fastq file. 
 */
 
process TRIM {

    tag { pair_id }

    input:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path(trimmed_reads), emit: trimmed_fastqs
    path "${pair_id}/*.atria.log*", emit: logs

    script:
    def (r1, r2) = reads

    trimmed_reads = reads.collect {
        "${pair_id}/${it.baseName}.atria.fastq"
    }

    """
    atria \\
        -r "${r1}" \\
        -R "${r2}" \\
        -o "${pair_id}" \\
        -t 1 \\
        -l 12 \\
        -q 30
    """
}

/*
 * define the `SAM_FOR_STRAND` process that creates a SAM file
 * to be used by `STRAND_CHECK` process to determine 
 * the strandedness of each fastq file pair. 
 */
 
process SAM_FOR_STRAND {

    input:
    path index
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    path "${pair_id}.sam"

    script:
    """
    bowtie2 -x "${index.baseName}" -1 ${reads[0]} -2 ${reads[1]} -S ${pair_id}.sam
    """
}


workflow {

    index_ch = INDEX(params.ref_genome)

    gtf2bed_ch=GTF2BED(params.gtf_file)

    read_pairs_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads, checkIfExists:true)

    trim_out = TRIM(read_pairs_ch)

    sam_for_strand_ch = SAM_FOR_STRAND(index_ch, TRIM.out.trimmed_fastqs)

}
```

I've tried passing the *index* argument directly to the script in the SAM_FOR_STRAND Alignmnet process, it gave the  "index.1.bt2" does not exist error. Then I tried giving the basename of the index files (as shown in the below). It still does not work, even though the index files are being created properly.

```
 /*
     * define the `SAM_FOR_STRAND` process that creates a SAM file
     * to be used by `STRAND_CHECK` process to determine 
     * the strandedness of each fastq file pair. 
     */
     
    process SAM_FOR_STRAND {
    
        input:
        path index
        tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)
    
        output:
        path "${pair_id}.sam"
    
        script:
        """
        bowtie2 -x "${index.baseName}" -1 ${reads[0]} -2 ${reads[1]} -S ${pair_id}.sam
        """
    }
```

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we run Bowtie2, we just need to make sure we supply the index basename using `-x`. This is the index filename prefix minus the `.X.bt2` extension. A safe assumption is that the first file in the collection of output files (sorted in lexicographical order) has the `.1.bt2` suffix. We can then just strip this off to get the required prefix. For example:

```
process SAM_FOR_STRAND {

    input:
    path index_files, stageAs: "bt2_index/*"
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    path "${pair_id}.sam"

    script:
    def idx = index_files[0].getBaseName(2)    

    """
    bowtie2 \\
        -x "${idx}" \\
        -1 "${reads[0]}" \\ 
        -2 "${reads[1]}" \\ 
        -S "${pair_id}.sam"
    """
}
```